# Convert file with map like structure text into an actual HashMap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this file below that has a map like structure in every line

```
sampledatamap.txt
```

```
field1=value1,  field2=value2,  field3=value3 ...
field1=value10, field2=value11, field3=value12 ...
```

How can I read the file and convert each line to a map using Java 8 stream? Thank you in advance.

Comment: start with `Files::readLines` or the like; then think how you can parse a single line (`Pattern::splitAsStream` probably), then look at `Stream::flatMap` then at `collect(Collectors.toMap)` then profit.

Comment: Thanks for the response would you be able to show a small code on how to do this. I'm new with Java 8 stream.

Comment: @zorlac The intent here is to let you try and help when you're stuck. Follow what Eugene said in comments and try to implement it. Ask doubts when stuck in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stream of lines, split each by commas, then by '=' and collect into the Map. Then collect Maps into the List. For example:

```
public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("sampledatamap.txt");

        try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            List<Map<String, String>> collect = lines
                    .map(Parser::toMap)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(collect);
        }
    }

    static Map<String, String> toMap(String line) {
        return Stream
                .of(line.split(","))
                .map(s -> s.split("="))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap((String[] s) -> s[0], (String[] s) -> s[1]));
    }
}
```

May be not the cleanest solution, but the idea is shown.

Comment: Also he seems to ask for a Map per line, not all in the same Map ;)

Comment: @azro Oops, i did not notice this condition :) But correction is very simple, edited.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Map<String, String>> result = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("sampledatamap.txt"))
    .stream()
    // transform each line into a stream of "field=value" format
    .map(lineStr -> Stream.of(lineStr.split(",")))
    .map(line -> line
        // transform each of "field=value" format into a Map
        .map(rawStr -> {
            Map<String, String> entry = new HashMap<>();
            String[] kv = rawStr.trim().split("=");
            entry.put(kv[0], kv[1]);
            return entry;
        })
        // merge all the single entry map into a full map
        .reduce(new HashMap<>(), (a, b) -> {
            a.putAll(b);
            return a;
        }))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```